# Attiny204 Interrupt Flag Not Being Generated

Tags: interrupt, avr, atmelstudio, isr

I'm trying to write a (fairly) basic bit of software for and Attiny204, which handles interrupts when a clock input is pulled high.

When I run the code in the debug simulator in Atmel Studio, and set the clock input high, there is no interrupt flag generated. The interrupts do trigger when I manually produce an interrupt flag.

I've tried using different pins, and even, the other port. I can't seem to get the simulator to produce the interrupt flag.

In the past, I have used the AtMega328P in the simulator with equivalent code, and it works fine.

```
ISR(PORTA_PORT_vect)
{
  //In this function we must:
  //1. Shift all data up
  shiftUp();

  //2. Get new 8th bit
  bit8 = VPORTA.IN & (1 << 1);

  //3. Set Data Output Pin to bit0
  if(bit0 == 0)
    VPORTA.OUT &= ~(1 << 3);
  else
    VPORTA.OUT |= (1 << 3);

  //4. Calculate new dimValue and dimMilliseconds
  calcDim();
  calcDelay();
}

int main(void)
{
  initVariables();
  /*
    Below this, we must set the Data Direction (DD) of each pin we assigned.
  */

  //Below, set the ISC of the Zero Cross Pin and the Clock Pin to allow interrupts
  PORTA_PIN0CTRL |= 0b00000001; //Zero Cross
  //PORTA_PIN1CTRL = 0b00000000; //Data In
  //PORTA_PIN2CTRL = 0b00000000; //Data Next
  //PORTA_PIN3CTRL = 0b00000000; //Triac Control

  PORTB_PIN0CTRL |= 0b00000001; //Clock

  //VPORTB.INTFLAGS |= 0b00000001;

  //Set Port direction.
  VPORTA.DIR = 0x30;
  VPORTB.DIR = 0x00;

  /*
    Below this, we must enable interrupts.
  */
  sei();
  /* Replace with your application code */
  while (1) 
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get ISR on rise edge, you should set PINCTRL to 0x2 afaik. What do you mean by clock input, PB0 as simple GPIO? I think you should manually clear ISR flag.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I just labeled it as "clock" because I'm doing a simple synchronous data transmission. I'll look into clearing the ISR bit.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing to `VPORTA` and `VPORTB`? The Tiny204 doesn´t have this registers.
You enable interrupts on both edges for Pin 0 of Port A (`PIN0CTRL` bit 0 is set = `BOTHEDGES`) and you don´t clear the interrupt flag in your ISR of Port A. Please take a look at the data sheet:

`The interrupt request remains active until the interrupt flag is cleared. See the peripheral's INTFLAGSregister for details on how to clear interrupt flags.`

Comment: You're right, sorry about that; I am actually using the AtTiny214 which has both Port A and Port B. I will have to look into clearing the ISR flag. Thank you!

Comment: Upon trying to clear the interrupt flag, the flag never triggers, by itself unless I set the ISC flags to low level sensing.

Do you think it could be the simulator not detecting a rising edge, and just seeing it as a solid state?

Comment: Now I have some trouble with understanding your interrupt source.
Are you trying to detect a rising edge or a low-level interrupt? Because you set the flags for a low-level interrupt and you configure the interrupt for edges. That are two different interrupts. You can not trigger an edge interrupt with a low level.

Comment: Again, sorry for the confusion. At this point, I want a rising edge, but I'm just trying to figure out why it won't work. That is the reason I attempted to use the low level interrupt.